# ionic2 and ng2-resource-rest missing typings

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

How I can include a module that has no npm @typings?
I want to include ng2-resource-rest into an ionic2 application. I was able to start an angular2 project with the module, but when I tried to do the same with ionic2 i get the error:

```
ionic-rest/node_modules/ng2-resource-rest/index.js does not export ResourceModule (imported by /Users/vlado/code/tests/ionic-rest/.tmp/app/app.module.js)
```

The module have .d.ts files but ... I am missing something
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the lib to ver 1.4.7. Please try it.